# I can't get this mean calculated, it just displays 0 all the time

Tags: c, mean

I cant get this to show the mean, where have a made a mistake? it just seems to skip past the mean function altogether for some reason.

```
#include <stdio.h>
double mean(double n[10], int i);

int main()
{
    double n[10];
    int i;
    double x = 0, ave;

    for (i = 0 ; i < 10 && x >= 0 ; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter your value\n");
        scanf("%f", &n[i]);
        printf("%d", n[i]);
    }
    if (i == 10)
    {
        printf("maximum quantity of values reached\n");
    }
    ave = mean(n, i);
    printf("%f", ave);
    return 0;
}
double mean(double n[],int i)
{
    int j;
    double sum = 0.0;
    for (j = 0 ; j < i ; j++)
    {
        sum += n[j];
    }
    return (sum / i);
}
```

Comment: Did you try compiling with warnings enabled?

Comment: First mistake `scanf("%f", &n[i])` where `n` is an array of `double` when it should be `float`, and you should check that `scanf()` did succeed, otherwise you will invoke undefined behavior if you assume it did.

Comment: Can you show us what values you inputted to get the `0` sum result?

Comment: See with warnings enabled `error: format '%f' expects argument of type 'float *', but argument 2 has type 'double *'`.

Comment: well i just put in like 4 different sets of it, but when i did the 2nd printf to check it had scanned in it only ever said it had 1.0000...

Comment: `scanf("%f", &n[i]);
        printf("%d", n[i]);` --> `scanf("%lf", &n[i]);
        printf("%f\n", n[i]);`

Comment: sorry guys as you can tell im a total noob at this xD

Comment: Always enable all warnings when compiling, then fix those warnings.  (for gcc, at a minimum, use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` )

Comment: regarding this line: `for (i = 0 ; i < 10 && x >= 0 ; i++)`,  the value of 'x' is not changed within the loop, so why have the check of the value?

Comment: this might be nit picking, but when writing double constants, write them with a decimal point, so `0` would be better written as `0.0`

Comment: after correcting the two warnings, the code worked correctly for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    scanf("%f", &n[i]);
    printf("%d", n[i]);
```

The directive `%f` denotes that the argument is of type `float *` for `scanf` and `double` (which `float` values get promoted to) for `printf`... which makes me wonder why you chose to use `%d` for `printf`?

The `%d` directive denotes that the argument is of type `int *` for `scanf` and `int` for `printf`.

`&n[i]` is of type `double *`, so you're lying to `scanf`. `n[i]` is of type `double`, so you're also lying to `printf`. Both of these lies produce undefined behaviour. See [section 7.21.6.2, paragraph 10](http://www.iso-9899.info/n1570.html@7.21.6.2p10) which state:

> ... If this object does not have an appropriate type, or if the result of the conversion cannot be represented in the object, the behavior is undefined.

... and [section 7.21.6.1, paragraph 9](http://www.iso-9899.info/n1570.html#7.21.6.1p9) which states:

> ... If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.

You should be using the `%lf` directive for `scanf`. As I mentioned earlier, the `%f` directive will work just fine for printing `double`s (or `float`s, due to the aforementioned promotion), but you could also use `%lf` for printing `float`s or `double`s using `printf` if you choose to do so.

You should probably also be checking the return value of `scanf` before you go using those values, because there's no guarantee regarding their sanity (e.g. perhaps the user entered filthy non-numeric data) unless you do so.

Comment: Very good answer, with good references to the appropriate documents. I would delete mine but I don't think it interferes with yours in any way. Your answer should be accepted.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things to fix, the most important one is

```
scanf("%f", &n[i])
```

this is *undefined behavior*, because `"%f"` expects a pointer to `float` not `double`, you should change it to

```
scanf("%lf", &n[i])
```

or change the type of `n` to `float`.

Another problem is that `x` never changes, so the condition `x >= 0` is always true no matter what the input is. Perhaps you mean

```
x = n[i];
```

inside the loop.

The last suggestion introduces a new problem, you don't check the return value of `scanf()` so you cannot guarantee that `x >= 0` is defined behavior.

This is a fix I can suggest

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

double mean(double n[10], int i);
int getdouble(double *value);

int main()
{
    double n[10];
    int i;
    double x = 0, ave;

    for (i = 0 ; ((i < 10) && (x >= 0)) ; i++)
    {
        int retry;
        do
        {
            printf("Enter the %ith value > ", i + 1);
            retry += 1;
        } while ((getdouble(&n[i]) != 0) && (retry < 10));
        x = n[i];
    }

    if (i == 10)
        printf("maximum quantity of values reached\n");
    ave = mean(n, i);

    printf("%f", ave);
    return 0;
}
double mean(double n[], int count)
{
    int j;
    double sum = 0.0;
    for (j = 0 ; j < count ; j++)
        sum += n[j];
    return sum / ((double) count);
}

int getdouble(double *value)
{
    char buffer[100];
    char *endptr;
    if (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin) == NULL)
        return -1;
    *value = strtod(buffer, &endptr);
    if ((*endptr != '\0') && (isspace((unsigned char) *endptr) == 0))
        return -1;
    return 0;
}
```

Note that, I don't use `scanf()` since it's to difficult to do it right.

Comment: is the change of %f to %lf the same for the printf's too?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Let me do it then.

Comment: I feel like I always forget these details, it's so hard to remember all of them. Specially when you stop using `double` and `float` for a long time like it appears to be in my case now.

Comment: @iharob They are rather inconsistent. I found it helped once I knew that historically, `%lf` stood for `long float`, which was a synonym for `double`...

Comment: That's why it's there then! And indeed, the c11 standard clearly states that it HAS NO EFFECT over any of the floating point conversion specifiers.

Comment: `(int) *endptr` should be `(unsigned char)*endptr`